# AS3 tweening a Movie clips Y postion based on it's current Y position — (which varies)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently working on some Navigation, and I would like to move (and tween) a movie clip's y position on click. I have multiple items with in the nav movie clip, so I'd like to set the start position based on the movie clips current Y position. Currently I'm using this format:

```
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(iconnav, "y", Strong.easeOut, 2206, 2001, 18, false);
myTween.stop();
```

is it possible to modify the "2206" start value to something that references the movieclip's current y position. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You mean `iconnav.y`?

Comment: `var myTween:Tween = new Tween(iconnav, "y", Strong.easeOut, iconnav.y, 2001, 18, false);
myTween.stop();` I thought I would do this, just to make sure Marty Wallace was clear. :D

Comment: Ahh Pefect and simple. Thanks Fellas!

Comment: Actually, looks like setting it iconnav.y, seems to make the starting point at the movieclips original y position, where as I want it to reference the current position each time. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `iconnav.y` is iconnav's current position. The problem may be that you seem to be setting up the tween and pausing it, I suspect you are then moving iconnav which means the .y has since moved from when you first setup the tween. Either set up the the moment you need it or use `myTween.begin = iconnav.y` just before you do `myTween.start();`. But this last suggestion is a total guess. I have never actually changed myTween.begin before but I presume it is what you would be after. I, honestly, would create the tween when needed instead.